# Error "MSBUILD : error : Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream." using Visula Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am using  Visual studio 2013 version 12.0.21005.1.

I downloaded the Basic Camera Sample from 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Camera-Sample-52dae359

When I try to compile this sample I got an error
"MSBUILD : error : Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream."

I saw the .Xap file is generated with 0 length. I tried to delete the XAP file and rebuild. It still hit the error.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are not having all files required on the buildserver.

Try re-installing the Visual Studio again